# Problem with the compilation in the truffle framework

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, truffle-contract, truffle-compile

I made a smart contract in Remix-Solidity IDE, when I compiled it I had no errors and I was able to remove the contract but when I tried to use the truffle for my Dapp and compiled it it showed me this error.

[image]

this is the warning that shows remix-solidity, some tell me that it is necessary to declare if they are public or private, I made the same changes but it does not let me compile.

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details (exceptions, smart contract code). it might be a compiler version issue.

Comment: there are the warnings, even if I display the contract in the network rinkeby and use the functions of the contract and I registered all the transactions. Now I was trying to make an app that consumes the contract.

Comment: Perhaps there is a mismatch in complier versions?

In any case we need more details :), at least can you post the contract itself?

Comment: In the end it is mismatch of the truffle compiler, the version it uses is 0.5.0

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that the truffle framework had a different version of the solidity pragma, my contract used the 0.4.23 and truffle 0.5.0